# How can I remove rows from a dataframe based on having NA in two columns?

Tags: r, na

The dataframe is called **a**. It has 4000 rows across 20 columns.

Two of the columns are called **ndc** and **ndtem**. I need to remove rows that have NA in those two columns and keep everything else

I tried these methods:

```
a<- a[complete.cases(a[, c("ndc", "ndtem")]), ]

a <- a[!(is.na(a$ndc) | is.na(a$ndtem)), ]

a <- a %>% filter(!is.na(ndc) & !is.na(ndtem))
```

Please correct my code or help me with an alternative.

Comment: Any of those methods would have worked.  Check whether you have correct `NA` values or is it a string `"NA"` i.e. `colSums(is.na(a[c("ndc", "ndtem")]))`

Comment: `complete.cases` is going to go false when _either_ of the columns is `NA`, not just when both are `NA`. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @akrun Thank you so much for the suggestion. My NA values were the problem. I fixed that and then my code ran smoothly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing rows for which either of the two columns has an `NA`.
To remove rows for which both columns are `NA` the following conditions would work:

```
a[!(is.na(a$ndc) & is.na(a$ndtem)), ]
a[!is.na(a$ndc) | !is.na(a$ndtem), ]
```

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
a %>% filter(!(is.na(ndc) & is.na(ndtem)))
```

Answer (score 0):

At the suggestion in the comments. I fixed my NAs. I had assigned them "NA" instead of just NA. Once I removed the quotation marks, I used

a <- a %>% filter(!is.na(ndc) & !is.na(ndtem))

And it worked perfectly.

Comment: How is this different from the other solution?